# update numpy array where not masked

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

My question is twofolded

First, lets say I've two numpy arrays, that are partially masked

```
array_old
[[-- -- -- --]
 [10 11 -- --]
 [12 14 -- --]
 [-- -- 17 --]]

array_update
[[--  5 -- --]
 [-- --  9 --]
 [-- 15  8 13]
 [-- -- 19 16]]
```

How to get create a new array, where all non-masked values are updated or ammended, like:

```
array_new
[[--  5 -- --]
 [10 11  9 --]
 [12 15  8 13]
 [-- -- 19 16]]
```

Secondly,
If possible, how to do above in a 3d numpy array?

**UPDATE:**

For the second part, now I use a for loop, using [@freidrichen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39869892/2459096) method as follows:

```
array = np.ma.masked_equal([[[0, 0, 0, 0], [10, 11, 0, 0], [12, 14, 0, 0], [0, 0, 17, 0]],[[0, 5, 0, 0], [0, 0, 9, 0], [0, 15, 8, 13], [0, 0, 19, 16]],[[0, 0, 0, 0], [5, 0, 0, 13], [8, 14, 0, 0], [0, 0, 17, 0]],[[6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 21], [0, 0, 0, 0]]], 0)

a = array[0,::]
for ix in range(array.shape[0] - 1):
    b = array[ix,::] 
    c = array[ix+1,::]
    b[~c.mask] = c.compressed()
    a[~b.mask] = b.compressed()
```

Not sure if that's the best solution

Comment: @holdenweb you are right, let me update and yes, where new non-masked values are available it should overwrite existing ones

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `a[~b.mask] = b.compressed()`.

`a[~b.mask]` selects all the values in `a` where `b` is not masked. `b.compressed()` is a flattened array with all the non-masked values in `b`.

Example:

```
>>> a = np.ma.masked_equal([[0, 0, 0, 0], [10, 11, 0, 0], [12, 14, 0, 0], [0, 0, 17, 0]], 0)
>>> b = np.ma.masked_equal([[0, 5, 0, 0], [0, 0, 9, 0], [0, 15, 8, 13], [0, 0, 19, 16]], 0)
>>> a[~b.mask] = b.compressed()
>>> a
[[-- 5 -- --]
[10 11 9 --]
[12 15 8 13]
[-- -- 19 16]]
```

This should work with 3d arrays too.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! What I actually ment with 3d arrays, is that one 3d array contains several 2d arrays/slices [as `array_update1`, `array_update2`], where the output is a 2d array filled with the most 'recent' values [and maybe no masked values anymore]