# remove value of numpy array while keeping the dimensions

Tags: python, numpy

I've a `numpy` array as follow:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, -999.],
              [2, 3, 4, -999.],
              [3, 4, 5, 6]])
```

How can I remove the value `-999.` while keeping the dimensions, as such:

```
array([[   1.,    2.,    3.],
       [   2.,    3.,    4.],
       [   3.,    4.,    5.,    6.]])
```

I tried:

```
np.delete(a, np.where(a == -999.))
```

But this result in

```
array([   3.,    2.,    3.,    4., -999.,    3.,    4.,    5.,    6.])
```

And I tried

```
a[a == -999.] = np.nan
a[~np.isnan(a)]
```

While it removes the `nan` (and so the `-999`), the `numpy` array becomes `1D`:

```
array([1., 2., 3., 2., 3., 4., 3., 4., 5., 6.])
```

**EDIT**

I use the resulting jagged array (list of lists) for slicing another array where each slice can have a different length.

My use-case:

```
a = np.random.randint(1,35,size=(100000,5))
a[a == 14] = -999 # set a missing value
```

Option 1, select values non equal fill value

```
%%timeit
slices = np.array([i[i != -999] for i in a])

10 loops, best of 3: 183 ms per loop
```

Option 2, mask and compress

```
%%timeit
a_ma = np.ma.masked_equal(a, -999)
slices = np.array([i.compressed() for i in a_ma])

1 loop, best of 3: 2.99 s per loop
```

Comment: NumPy does not really support jagged arrays.

Comment: As miradulo notes, numpy doesn't support [jagged arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array).  (Well, you could create an array of objects, but that probably wouldn't solve the problem in this case.  The result wouldn't act like a 2-d array.)  What are you going to do with the result?  Knowing the ultimate goal of your calculation will help guide the answers given here.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser thanks for your response. I've created a ipynb with my ultimate goal: https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/mattijn/pynotebook/blob/master/jagged-array-goal.ipynb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While jagged arrays are not really something you should be using, you could do the following using a list comprehension:

```
In [33]: a = np.array([i[i != -999.] for i in a])

In [34]: a
Out[34]:
array([array([ 1.,  2.,  3.]), array([ 2.,  3.,  4.]),
       array([ 3.,  4.,  5.,  6.])], dtype=object)

In [35]: a[0].shape
Out[35]: (3,)

In [36]: a[1].shape
Out[36]: (3,)

In [37]: a[2].shape
Out[37]: (4,)
```

Answer (score 1):

Which dimensions are you try to keep?  `a.shape` is `(3,4)`.  How can you 
remove 2 items from `a` and still have 3x4 array (3*4=12)?

Your desired display is not a (3,4) array:

```
In [638]: arr = np.array([[   1.,    2.,    3.],
     ...:        [   2.,    3.,    4.],
     ...:        [   3.,    4.,    5.,    6.]])
     ...:        
In [639]: arr
Out[639]: 
array([list([1.0, 2.0, 3.0]), list([2.0, 3.0, 4.0]),
       list([3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0])], dtype=object)
In [640]: arr.shape
Out[640]: (3,)
```

Because the rows vary in length, it creates an object dtype array, one element per row.  That is basically a list of lists.

For some purposes it is handy to make a `MaskedArray`:

```
In [637]: np.ma.masked_equal(a, -999)
Out[637]: 
masked_array(
  data=[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, --],
        [2.0, 3.0, 4.0, --],
        [3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0]],
  mask=[[False, False, False,  True],
        [False, False, False,  True],
        [False, False, False, False]],
  fill_value=-999.0)
```

I see you have worked with `MaskedArrays` before: [update numpy array where not masked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39869524/update-numpy-array-where-not-masked)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I would love to use `MaskedArrays`, but my subsequent step is to used the jagged array for slicing another array, which I cannot using a `MaskedArray`. Maybe thats my real problem. My ultimate goal in a notebook: https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/mattijn/pynotebook/blob/master/jagged-array-goal.ipynb